# Issues when trying to write multiple files using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple subfolders with multiple text files each. I would like to read files from each subfolder one by one, make some changes, and output to new subfolders with similar names but in a different directory. Below is my program, but when I run it I only get one output file. What am I doing wrong?

```
import os
rootdir = 'dir'
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for fname in files:
            print os.path.join(subdir, fname)
            file_path = os.path.join(subdir, fname)
            df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='|', encoding='cp1252')
            df['X1]=df['X1’].astype(str)
            df['X2']=df['X2'].astype(str)
            df.to_excel('out_dir\out_subfolder\fname.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
df.to_excel('out_dir\out_subfolder\fname.xlsx')
```

is saving the DataFrame to `'out_dir\out_subfolder\fname.xlsx'`.

You want it to save to:

```
os.path.join(out_dir, out_subfolder, fname + '.xlsx')
```

So it uses the variables, rather than the fixed string. So use:

```
df.to_excel(os.path.join(out_dir, out_subfolder, fname + '.xlsx'))
```